# Insert in mysql view gives wrong output

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, sql-view

I am new to mysql views,just came along this problem
I have 3 tables

```
personal(name,age,village)
office(id,company,location)
entertainment(sport,team,music)
```

Now I create a view using the following syntax

```
mysql> CREATE VIEW person AS
    ->  SELECT personal.name,personal.age,personal.village,office.id,office.comp
any,office.location,entertainment.sport,entertainment.team,entertainment.music
    -> FROM personal,office,entertainment;
```

Next I insert into person view

```
 INSERT INTO person(name,age,village) VALUES ('jay','40','Pune');
 INSERT INTO person(id,company,location) VALUES ('36234','AZcD','Mumbai');
 INSERT INTO person(sport,team,music) VALUES ('football','KKR','POP');
```

I get the output with this properly.(I had to insert sepeartely or else it gives me an error)

```
 +------+------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------+------+-------+

| name | age  | village | id    | company | location | sport    | team | music |

+------+------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------+------+-------+

| jay  |   40 | Pune    | 36234 | AZcD    | Mumbai   | football | KKR  | POP   |

+------+------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------+------+-------+
```

The problem arises now,when I try to insert the same insert queries again with different values ,I get the following output

```
+-------+------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------+------+-----
------+
| name  | age  | village | id    | company | location | sport      | team | musi
c     |
+-------+------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------+------+-----
------+
| jay   |   40 | Pune    | 36234 | AZcD    | Mumbai   | football   | KKR  | POP
      |
| Rohit |   42 | Goa     | 36234 | AZcD    | Mumbai   | football   | KKR  | POP
      |
| jay   |   40 | Pune    | 86234 | YZcD    | Kolkata  | football   | KKR  | POP
      |
| Rohit |   42 | Goa     | 86234 | YZcD    | Kolkata  | football   | KKR  | POP
      |
| jay   |   40 | Pune    | 36234 | AZcD    | Mumbai   | basketball | CSK  | Boll
ywood |
| Rohit |   42 | Goa     | 36234 | AZcD    | Mumbai   | basketball | CSK  | Boll
ywood |
| jay   |   40 | Pune    | 86234 | YZcD    | Kolkata  | basketball | CSK  | Boll
ywood |
| Rohit |   42 | Goa     | 86234 | YZcD    | Kolkata  | basketball | CSK  | Boll
ywood |
+-------+------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------+------+-----
------+
```

I get 7 new records instead of just 1.And if you see closely the last record is the right record,I mean the record i inserted.
What am I doin wrong?
The tables are proper after the above  queries:

```
mysql> select * from personal;
+-------+------+---------+
| name  | age  | village |
+-------+------+---------+
| jay   |   40 | Pune    |
| Rohit |   42 | Goa     |
+-------+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from office;
+-------+---------+----------+
| id    | company | location |
+-------+---------+----------+
| 36234 | AZcD    | Mumbai   |
| 86234 | YZcD    | Kolkata  |
+-------+---------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from entertainment;
+------------+------+-----------+
| sport      | team | music     |
+------------+------+-----------+
| football   | KKR  | POP       |
| basketball | CSK  | Bollywood |
+------------+------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please help.

Comment: When you don't specify a JOIN between the tables you get a full cartesian product of all the data, i.e., you get all the combination of the tables you have in your select.
In this case you have 3 tables with 2 records each. 2*2*2 will give you 8 records.In the end, this is simply a bad design. You should read up on JOINs and table structures before start something like this and then realize later on the mess you got yourself into

Comment: I tried JOIN too still it doesnt work this  is the query i tried 
`mysql> CREATE VIEW persona AS
    -> SELECT personal.p_id,personal.name,personal.village,office.company,office
.location
    -> FROM personal JOIN office ON personal.p_id=office.o_id;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)`
Once I insert it says the view is empty whereas the tables get populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a conception problem in your db.

There is no relationships between your tables. They contain all different data, with no reference to other table. For example, i think `personal` table should contain an `office_id`, which would be a foreign key (ie reference) of `office` table.

For example :

```
mysql> select * from personal;
+-------+------+---------+-----------+
| name  | age  | village | office_id |
+-------+------+---------+-----------+
| jay   |   40 | Pune    | 36234     |
| Rohit |   42 | Goa     | 86234     |
+-------+------+---------+-----------+
```

And then, you could get a person with his corresponding office with this request :

```
SELECT personal.name,personal.age,personal.village,office.id,office.company,office.location
    FROM personal,office WHERE personal.office_id = office.id;
```

OR (with a real JOIN) :

```
SELECT personal.name,personal.age,personal.village,office.id,office.company,office.location
    FROM personal JOIN office ON personal.office_id = office.id;
```

You should think your database structure again, then adapt your view by adding joins between tables.

Be careful with `insert` statements using views : you can have weird behaviours. I always prefer to make `insert` statements directly into tables.

Comment: I tried inserting in the tables too as you said in your last line,but I get the same result...if I insert in personal(table) and check my view,I see the new inserted record and the old record on the same row.

Comment: This is normal : because there is no relationship between your tables, SQL returns you all possible combinations. You got 2 rows in each table, so 2*2*2 : 8. This is the number of rows you get when selecting your view, isn't it ?

Comment: You  suggest I should connect it right?I will give a try then

Comment: cant i put 2 where clauses?since I have a 3rd table also.I wanted to put something like this                                                                    
 WHERE office.o_id=personal.p_id
 WHERE entertainment.e_id=personal.p_id;

Comment: No, there is only one `WHERE` clause in a query. But you can have several conditions, just link them with `AND` or `OR` : `WHERE office.o_id=personal.p_id AND entertainment.e_id=personal.p_id;`

Comment: ok I did as you said,but the view is an empty set,whereas the tables are populated but the view is empty.This is the query i used to create the view                                                                  
mysql> CREATE VIEW person AS
    -> SELECT personal.p_id,personal.name,personal.village,office.company,office
.location,entertainment.sport,entertainment.team
    -> FROM personal,office,entertainment
    -> WHERE office.o_id=personal.p_id AND entertainment.e_id=personal.p_id;

Comment: also the o_id and e_id are null,its not saving the p_id in it..this is from the subsequent tables(office and entertainmet)

Comment: You join both tables to the same column : `personal.p_id`. This is not normal. Read some documents about database designing, for example [this one](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/03/17/the-basics-of-good-database-design-in-web-development/).

Comment: I tried with just 2 tables:office and personal and still the view is empty.

Comment: somehow I feel the where clause is creating a problem

Comment: The questions you got to ask yourself are : Is personal your main data (I mean the main data, all others are linked to it) ? How many offices a personal can be linked to ? How many entertainements a personal can be linked to ?

Comment: this is the my first program i took as an example.Consider just 2 tables for now,personal and office.Consider personal to be a main program,and office is connected to it.Please it would be great if you could write me the view if possible

Comment: I already wrote it in my answer, the two example `SELECT` statements I put could be used for your view body. A view is nothing more than a query. have you modified your personal table well ? I mean add the office_id column as I wrote it ?

Comment: I havent added a foreign key to  the office table,I was trying to add now but it gave me this error `ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint` is it impt to have a primary key along with a foreign key in the table?the table I was creating `mysql> create table office(
    -> o_id int(11),
    -> company varchar(40),
    -> location varchar(40),
    -> foreign key (o_id) references personal(p_id)
    -> );`

Comment: P_id is the primary key and o_id the foreign referenced to p_id

Comment: NO : read again what I wrote. This column office_id should be added to **personal** table. We won't be able to help you if you don't give attention to what we say.

Comment: I did everythin again.This is what I did,created a office table with id as primary key,then i created a personal table with office_id as the foreign key with references to the id of the office table.Next I created a view with the same query you gave above.Then i inserted a record `INSERT INTO person(name,village) VALUES ('Mohit','Chennai');` and `INSERT INTO person(id,company,location) VALUES ('121','GGCD','Goa');`,now when I check the view it shows me empty but the tables are populated although the office_id in the personal table is NULL.

Comment: You must give personal.office_id field a value, to indicate to which office your personal is linked. I seriously advice you to read some documentation again, I don't think you understand really well database designing, tables structure and relationships between them. Read carefully the answer I wrote 1 hour ago : there is all information you need. Look the first code i put : when I make a SELECT statement on personal table, office_id has a value for both rows.

Comment: doesnt the personal.office_id take in values from office.id?I mean when i write a value for office.id,doesnt the same value come in the personal.office_id?

Comment: No : personal.office_id must contain an office id. This is the data which makes the link between a personal and an office : It means "this personal is linked to the office which have this id". This is called a foreign key : a reference to a row of another table. For example, if you need your personal to be able to be linked to several offices, you will have to create an intermediate table, which contain only 2 columns : personal_id and office_id. This table would only make the link between a personal and an office. **AGAIN, PLEASE READ DOCUMENTATION ABOUT DATABASE DESIGNING AND TABLES LINKS**